# infinite system MAX-SAT

Tags: satisfiability

Is there a generalization of maximal satisfaction (MAX-SAT) based on infinitely many variables? One natural occurrence of such problem is the general Ising model in material science.

Comment: Crossposted [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/185977/max-sat-for-infinite-system), [here](https://www.or-exchange.org/questions/10603/infinite-version-of-max-sat), and [here](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/16062/max-sat-for-infinite-system).